# Getting and ordering rows with value greater than zero then rows with value zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id    title    display_order
1     t1       3
2     t2       1
3     t3       5
4     t4       4
5     t5       2
6     t6       0
7     t7       7
8     t8       6
9     t9       0
10    t10      0
```

What I need is to have results like this

```
id    title    display_order
2     t2       1
5     t5       2
1     t1       3
4     t4       4
3     t3       5
8     t8       6
7     t7       7
...order of the rest is not important but should be in the result
6     t6       0
9     t9       0
10    t10      0
```

I can get this result with two SQL queries and then combine them.

Is there a way to do this with one SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM atable
ORDER BY
  display_order = 0,
  display_order
```

When `display_order` is 0, the first sorting term, `display_order = 0`, evaluates to `True`, otherwise it evaluates to `False`. `True` sorts after `False` – so, the first sorting criterion makes sure that rows with the `display_order` of 0 are sorted at the end of the list.

The second ORDER BY term, `display_order`, additionally specifies the order for rows with the non-zero order values.

Thus, the two criteria give you the desired sorting order.

Answer (score 3):

Try the below one-

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
ORDER BY IF (display_order = 0, 9999999, display_order)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution in T-SQL in case anyone needs it

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY CASE WHEN display_order = 0 THEN display_order END ASC,CASE WHEN display_order > 0 THEN display_order  END ASC
```

Comment: excellent. this works for me 