# Django model queryset usage of .extra() or union to apply a custom sort on a PositiveIntegerField

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

For a gallery of items a user can sort manually some items to always make them appear first.

For that the model have a "sort" not null PositiveIntegerField (default to 0). Items with sort field greater than zero are sorted manually and must appear before not sorted items with sort value at 0.

The SQL query which may be used could be something like this:

```
(select photo, sort, 0 as priority from photos where sort > 0)
union all
(select photo, sort, 1 as priority from photos where sort = 0)
order by priority, sort
```

Results would looks like:

```
+---------+------+----------+
| photo   | sort | priority |
+---------+------+----------+
| photo-a | 1    | 0        |
| photo-b | 2    | 0        |
| photo-c | 0    | 1        |
| photo-d | 0    | 1        |
| photo-e | 0    | 1        |
| ...                       |
```

But I can't figure out how it should be done properly with Django Queryset?

I'm able to merge two different queryset with `list(chain(q1, q2))` but queries are executed and this is inefficient with large collections, specially if my queryset should then be passed to django.core.paginator which normally would apply a LIMIT OFFSET clause for pagination. Of course, I could apply the slicing on each query `q1` and `q2` but this is a bit ugly as it overlap with what paginator does.

Maybe I'm trying to do it the wrong way. Or perhaps it should be done with the [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method?

Comment: can you explain in more detail why `Photo.objects.all().order('-sort')` does not suffice?

Comment: I detailed my problem, that may answer why a descending order_by on sort is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing an union/merge of querysets is not the solution. A much more simple solutions is to use a comparison in the order statement. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7632163/523104) on stackeoverflow pointed me to this neat solution.

```
select * from photos order by sort=0, sort
```

0=0 is evaluated as True which equal 1, 1=0 is False which equal 0 etc. got it?

Translated into Django Queryset :

```
Photos.objects.extra(select={'sortiszero': 'sort = 0'}, order_by=['sortiszero', 'sort'])
```

Results:

```
+---------+------+
| photo   | sort |
+---------+------+
| photo-a | 1    |
| photo-b | 2    |
| photo-c | 0    |
| photo-d | 0    |
| photo-e | 0    |
| ...            |
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

You should give more details.

If you want to union this two sets you can simply add lists:

```
list1 = SomeModel.objects.filter(sort != 0).order_by('column_name_1','column_name_2')
list2 = SomeModel.objects.filter(sort = 0).order_by('priority','foo')
return list = list1 + list2
```

Or if you want to use extra() method, here is an exaple:

```
list = SomeModel.objects.fooMethod().extra(order_by=[foo,])
```

Comment: I provided more details. Regarding your solution I have an error when I try to concatenate two Querysets with the + operand. `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'`. So I use `list(chain(q1, q2))` but this execute the queries before django.core.paginator can apply a slicing to have the LIMIT OFFSET clauses applied.

Comment: You should add lists not querysets: 
`for p in p_list:
list = Object.objects.filter(point = p)
return_list = return_list + list`